# Generate random data for test

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I want to run some tests with Hadoop, I have a large cluster (about 50 Tb), and I want to generate data for running some tests. Firstly I want to test hive performance, for that I want to generate structured data (CSV). Can someone please advice me the best way to achieve that.

Comment: try this :http://www.generatedata.com/#

Answer (score 4):

The first problem is you want to fake the mapreduce job into starting up mappers without any data. By default, it'll start up 1 map task per block, so let's fool it.

To do that, start out by creating some "fake files" in hdfs

```
for i in {1..100}; do echo "hello $i" | hadoop fs -put - fakes/$i.txt ; done
```

This will actually take a while... maybe a couple minutes.

Then, write a MapReduce job that "reads" these files. In the Map task, don't actually use any of that data. Generate your random data in that map function, and write it out (`context.write`). When your MapReduce job runs, it'll start 100 map tasks that will all generate your random data in parallel.

Set the number of reducers to 0, you don't need any here.

Comment: https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch7/RandomDataGenerationDriver.java  <-- here is a cool way of doing it with an input format